# can I use dynamic scaffolding without its domain class

Tags: grails

I have only `LoginController` which is

```
class LoginController {

    static scaffold = true

    def index = {
        render(view: "login.gsp")
    }
}
```

but I do not have `Login` domain class. If I use `static scaffold = true` in `LoginController`, will it work?

Comment: If you don't have a Domain class called Login then it won't have anything to scaffold. Thus, scaffolding won't work. Was that the question? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: ya that was the question when I run application its giving me the error which is ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Cannot generate controller logic for scaffolded class true. It is not a domain class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a Domain class called `Login` then it won't have anything to scaffold. Thus, scaffolding won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't just the case that it won't work.  It doesn't even make sense to use scaffolding without a domain class.  The scaffolding is specifically to support CRUD.  Without a domain class there is nothing to C, R, U or D.